# connect Android app to MySQL database

Tags: php, android, mysql, server

I've designed an android app connected to remote MySQL database using PHP for the purpose of inserting data from the app to the database.

Currently I put PHP file in a local server XAMPP but in this case the server has to be always available so the application could work correctly.

Is there **any other places** to put or upload the PHP file to be online so anyone can test the application without the need for my local Server to be available.

Note that I can not upload it on the same MySQL database server because it already designed before.

Answer (score 1):

Better solution for this is to implement REST interface on the server side. On the Android side it would be just an implementation of HTTP requests (POST,GET,PUT) and data interpretation. There is no need to use any database connector on the client side.

For the implementation of REST client I would strongly suggest using [Volley library](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)(by Google).

Comment: As for the web service, there are plenty of free web services which provides PHP/java/python hosting all over the world. It is the _modern_ way how to communicate with server side from android application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe what you need is a server that supports PHP. There are many out there. If you are after a free solution, that you can test and people can use at the same time, suggest you , 000webhost.com. I cant say they are amazing etc, but they have what you need. You can send your requests there and allow php to CRUD to mysql DB.

Answer (score -2):

You can use WAMP sever on your system(PC or laptop) and put it online as shown. Just you have to do is to replace the IP from 'localhost' to 'xxx.xx.xx.xx' in your database connection file.
[image]

However, if you want your server available for 24 * 7, you can use some free web hosting services like [000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) (and many others. search on google). They give some free space for hosting sites and apps with back end having PHP.